# C++ templates question

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class T>
class ListNode {

public:
    T* data;
        ListNode<T>* next;
}
```

Lets say I have got a list node template and somewhere in the code I want to get a copy of the data - meaning not a copy of a pointer to data (T*) but a new pointer (T*) which will point to another place in the memory which have the same information there.

How can I do it when using C++ templates? How can I copy (*data) if I don't know what is the type of T.

Comment: How do you do it when you know the type? It works identically for template types.

Comment: You *do* know the type ... `T`

Comment: @Konrad: Or, it equally doesn't work for non-templates.  All the answers so far cause slicing.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler knows the type of **T**. What is does not know is how many instances of **T** are pointed to. In terms of getting a practical implementation, the short answer would be don't use pointer types. Use containers instead. Since you are copying the node data anyway the overhead is minimal. Explicit example below:

```
template <class T>
class ListNode {
public:
    // use a vector as the  container
    std::vector<T> data;
    ListNode<T>* next;
    // initializer from pointer primitive
    ListNode(const T* ps,size_t elements)
    {
        data.assign(ps,ps+elements);
    }
    // copy templated instance
    ListNode(const ListNode& arg)
    {
        data = arg.data;
    }
    // assignment
    ListNode& operator=(const ListNode& arg)
    {
        if (this != &arg)
        {
            data = arg.data;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Actual usage would be similar to this:

```
{
    const char* ps = "Hello World";
    ListNode<char> ln1(ps,strlen(ps));
    ListNode<char> ln2 = ln1;
}
```

You can, of course, get much more complicated solutions but they will all involve keeping track of the number of instances of type **T** to which your pointer points.

Comment: +1: despite scoping of example still a simple alternative and simple is good.

Answer (score 0):

T has to be copy-constructable so that you can do

```
   template <class T>
   ListNode<T>::ListNode(const ListNode<T>& src)
   {

        ...
        // given a preexisting copy, src, create a new T to
        // perform a copy
        T* destT = new T(*srcT);
   }
```

If T has a copy constructor, this will work. If it doesn't, the compiler will give you an error (probably a very cryptic one)

Comment: NM ... It does involve coffee, and it's not on your end.

Comment: why compiler should give error;
 Will not compiler generate a default copy constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

Use operator= or the copy constructor. It's standard practice that both of these will produce a copy of the object.

So, for example:

```
T *p = other_pointer;
*p = *data;
```

Or

```
T* copy = new T(*data);
```

Comment: For values of "produce a copy" which allow slicing.

Comment: @Ben: There is no standard virtual copy function so you take what you can get.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a copy of a templated type, practically you need not worry about the type as such and live that task on the copy constructor or assignment operator of that type:

```
template <class T>
class ListNode {
public:
    T* data;
    ListNode<T>* next;
    T* getCopy() { new T(*data); } // get copy of "data"
};
```

Suppose you use this `ListNode<T>` for `class A`, then you can have a copy constructor defined for A (and assignment operator as well):

```
class A {
public:
  A(const A& copy);
};
```

Now when `ListNode<T>::getCopy()` is called, it will call the copy constructor of A internally.

Comment: -1: Potentially leaking memory every time someone asks for a copy is probably not a good design ... wrap that in a smart pointer or preferably provide an explicit copy constructor and/or assignment operator.

Comment: @AJG85, I don't think so it's leaking memory. Questioner asks for copy of `T*`, which can be stored in `data` member of other object and can be deleted in destructor.

Comment: You return a copy like so: `T getCopy() const { *data; }` what you are doing is allocating memory on the heap and returning a pointer to it in a **public** method which could easily cause memory leaks and orphaned pointers ... whoever calls your method must store the pointer and call `delete` on it to avoid the memory leak with no exceptions.